# PHPUnit willReturnMap always returns null

Tags: php, mocking, phpunit

I have a unit test which uses the following mocked class

```
$this->stubHandle = $this->getMockBuilder(Handle::class)->disableOriginalConstructor()->getMock();
```

When I run

```
$key = new Key($this->stubHandle);
$this->stubHandle->method('__call')->will($this->returnCallback('var_dump'));
$key->nonExistingMethod('element0', 'element1', []);
```

it outputs

```
string(17) "nonExistingMethod"
```

and

```
array(3) {
  [0] =>
  string(8) "element0"
  [1] =>
  string(8) "element1"
  [2] =>
  array(0) {
  }
}
```

which I think it means the first argument of method `__call` is a string and the second argument is an array. No more arguments passed.

When I mock the return value of method `__call` like

```
$this->stubHandle->method('__call')->willReturn(1);
```

The return value is always `1` as expected.

When I mock the return value of method `__call` like

```
$this->stubHandle->method('__call')->willReturnMap(
    [
        ['argument1', null, 'returnValue'],
    ]
);
```

I expect the return value to be `'returnValue'` when the first argument of method `__call` is `'argument1'` while the seconds argument doesn't care.
If the first argument isn't `'argument1'`, I expect a return value of `null`.

Are these expectations correct?

No matter what I try, the return value is always `null` when I mock this value with method `willReturnMap`.

If my expectations are wrong, please lead me to a way to accomplish my goals to mock the return value, depending on the first argument (only) and also explain to me how to apply willReturnMap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems my search for method `willReturnMap` mislead me a bit.
I was under the assumption using `null` in the map, it would act as a "don't care", but it literally means `null`.

```
$this->stubHandle->method('__call')->willReturnMap(
    [
        ['nonExistingMethod', null, 'returnValue'],
    ]
);
```

means the arguments of method `__call` must explicitly be `'nonExistingMethod'` & `null` if you want the return value to be `'returnValue'`. Any other argument-values will return `null` instead.
E.g. `$key->nonExistingMethod(null);`

For the map to return `'returnValue'` in my example, it should have been:

```
$this->stubHandle->method('__call')->willReturnMap(
    [
        ['nonExistingMethod', ['element0', 'element1', []], 'returnValue'],
    ]
);
$key->nonExistingMethod('element0', 'element1', []);
```

In short...
When using argument mapping, the values can't be a "don't Care".